# Terraform nested for_each with data blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Im trying to use terraform to associate azure subscriptions to a management group.

The azurerm_management_group_subscription_association resource takes two inputs - the management group id and the subscription id. The documentation indicates you can't pass values directly and you have to use data blocks to get the values.

I've created a map variable that contains the subscription id and the management group id.

I am struggling to figure the correct syntax for this to work. Essentially I need to combine the id's from both data sources to create the management group association resource.

I've tried lots of different options and this is what I've got so far, but its still not working.

This is the map variable

```
subscription_mg_map = {
  1 : { subId = "1234", mgName = "MG-1" }, 
  2 : { subId = "5678", mgName = "MG-2" }
}
```

This is the code

```
data "azurerm_management_group" "mg" {
  for_each = var.subscription_mg_map
  name     = each.value["mgName"]
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "sub" {
  for_each        = var.subscription_mg_map
  subscription_id = each.value["subId"]
}

locals {
  data-details = flatten([
  for mg in data.azurerm_management_group.mg : [
  for sub in data.azurerm_subscription.sub : {
    mgid  = mg.id
    subId = sub.id
    }
  ]
  ])

  data-map = {
    for obj in local.data-details : "${obj.mgid}" => obj
  }
 }

resource "azurerm_management_group_subscription_association" "mgAssocation" {
  for_each = local.data-map

  management_group_id = each.key
  subscription_id     = each.value

}
```

this is the error I get

```
Error: Duplicate object key
│ 
│   on main.tf line 22, in locals:
│   21:   data-map = {
│   22:     for obj in local.data-details : "${obj.mgid}" => obj
│   23:   }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ obj.mgid is "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MG-1"
│ 
│ Two different items produced the key "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MG-1" in this 'for' expression. If
│ duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.
╵
╷
│ Error: Duplicate object key
│ 
│   on main.tf line 22, in locals:
│   21:   data-map = {
│   22:     for obj in local.data-details : "${obj.mgid}" => obj
│   23:   }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ obj.mgid is "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MG-2"
│ 
│ Two different items produced the key "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MG-2" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates
│ are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.
```

I can't see why its showing the duplicate key or if this is even the right way to approach it.

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting to the question?

Comment: added additional info and errors

Comment: Your code does not match your error message. Make sure that your code and error match, as clear the error was created from different code that in the question.

Comment: I don't understand - the code and errors do match up - I can share a screen shot of vs code to show this

Comment: @Marcin is definitely correct that the two error messages displayed each do not correspond to the two provided snippets of code. Please ensure the code in the question matches the code which produces the error messages.

Comment: I have fully revised the question

Comment: can you please show us what your expected output of your data-map should look like